# python module with module-wise global variable

Tags: python, module, global-variables, python-import

I made a python file with several functions in it and I would like to use it as a module. Let's say this file is called mymod.py. The following code is in it.

```
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer                      
porter = PorterStemmer()  

def tokenizer_porter(text):                                                                                    
    return [porter.stem(word) for word in text.split()]
```

Then I tried to import it in iPython and use tokenizer_porter:

```
from mymod import * 
tokenizer_porter('this is test')
```

The following error was generated

```
TypeError: unbound method stem() must be called with PorterStemmer instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I don't want to put porter inside the tokenizer_porter function since it feels redundant. What would be the right way to do this? Also, is it possible to avoid

```
from mymod import *
```

in this case?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access global variables in python you need to specify it in fucntion with `global` keyword

```
def tokenizer_porter(text):     
    global porter                                                                           
    return [porter.stem(word) for word in text.split()]
```

Comment: It works for me. Thanks. Is it possible to avoid from mymod import * in this case? I tried from mymod import tokenizer_porter and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried it after adding global? Cause it should work